# Is there a way to loop through all fields in a fieldset?

Tags: javascript, html, fieldset

I would like to change the class for all the fields in a specific fieldset.

Is there a way to loop through the fields in a fieldset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName`.

```
var fieldset= document.getElementById('something');
var fieldtags= ['input', 'textarea', 'select', 'button'];

for (var tagi= fieldtags.length; tagi-->0) {
    var fields= fieldset.getElementsByTagName(fieldtags[tagi]);
    for (var fieldi= fields.length; fieldi-->0;) {

        fields[fieldi].className= 'hello';
    }
}
```

(If you only care about `input` fields, you could lose the outer tag loop.)

If you needed them in document order (rather than grouped by tag) you'd have to walk over the elements manually, which will be a pain and a bit slow. You could use `fieldset.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select, button')`, but not all browsers support that yet. (In particular, IE6-7 predate it.)

Comment: THANK YOU for offering a viable solution that doesn't employ an entire library to do something so simple. +1

Comment: Question though, what's wrong with simply `fieldi--` ... isn't the `>0` test kind of redundant?

Comment: It's a general idiom for reverse (or order-irrelevant) iteration. It's redundant in this case, but otherwise it would be defensive against the top bound being lower than the bottom bound (in which case you'd get an infinite loop without the `>0`).

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery (yay!):

```
$('#fieldset-id :input').each(function(index,element) {
    //element is the specific field:
    $(element).doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Where did the OP mention that he/she is using jQuery?

Comment: @J-P just because they didn't explicitly say they aren't using jQuery doesn't mean it's not a viable option. It's overkill to bring in a library to solve this problem, but the next similar problem we save a little bit, and the time after that we save a little more and then it's worth it.

Comment: Well, why not explore all other possibilities then? MooTools? Prototype? Dojo? Ext? Qooxdoo? ... I think it's best to always assume that the OP wishes to use *no* library, unless explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

Note the solution below is for NON-JQUERY Implementations.

Implement a getElementsByClassName Method like this:

After you implement the code below you can then use document.getElementsByClassName("elementsInFieldSetClass")  it will return an array of the elements with that class.

```
function initializeGetElementsByClassName ()
        {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
                document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
                {
                    var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
                    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
                    var results = [];

                    var element;
                    for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
                        var elementClass = element.className;
                        if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                            results.push(element);
                    }
                    return results;
                }
            }
        }

window.onload = function () {
    initializeGetElementsByClassName();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another jQuery solution here.

If you are simply adding a class(es) to the elements, it's this simple:

```
$('fieldset :input').addClass('newClass');
```

.addClass() (like many other jQuery functions) will work on all of the elements that match the selector.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HANSG/8/

Answer (score -1):

Permanently? Find & replace in your editor of choice.

When the user clicks something? [jQuery](http://jquery.com) way:

```
$('fieldset <selector>').each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('old').addClass('new');
});
```